# how can I ssh from one AWS ec2 instance to another in the same region, AZ and are using the same security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I created 2 ec2 instances in the same region. I want to be able to ssh from one instance to another but I keep getting ssh timeout. I have created an inbound rule in the security group to allow ssh to both instance from anywhere. Also I have used the outbound rule to allow all traffic out. I am able to ssh directly to each machine but I can't ssh from one EC2 instance to another. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Both EC2 have Public and private IP address and are in the same SUBNET GROUP.

Comment: If both instances have the same SG then typically that SG would allow port 22 ingress from itself (from the SG itself) and you would SSH using private IPs (or hostnames as long as you're using Amazon provided DNS that resolves to the private IPs).

Comment: Thanks it works now. I think I was connecting from a different machine in a separate region.

Comment: If you have managed to solve your problem, feel free to add your own Answer to help future readers. However, if it was just a random error, you are welcome to delete your Question.

Comment: This issue was resolved by simply making sure I switched to the right region from the top right hand corner of the AWS console so that I can target the appropriate EC2 instances. So if anyone encounters this issue please verify that you are doing the SSH command from the intended server